# Installing BigQuery

Tags: ubuntu, google-bigquery

I tried to install big query on ubuntu and I got the following error:

```
Installed /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/oauth2-1.5.211-py2.6.egg
error: Installed distribution httplib2 0.6.0 conflicts with requirement httplib2>=0.7.4
```

How do I correct this issue?

Update:

I am trying to install the google BigQuery tools package found here...

http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/downloads/list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using `easy_install`, you could also try `easy_install -U httplib2` to upgrade the version of `httplib2` you're using.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to get your hands on a more up to date version of httplib2. You may need to build a newer version from source.

Try running `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

Comment: Still getting an error ## error: Installed distribution httplib2 0.7.2 conflicts with requirement httplib2>=0.7.4

Comment: Apparently ubuntu has a too old version of `httplib2` in their software repository. You have the option to A) wait, or B) follow these instructions: https://code.google.com/p/httplib2/wiki/Install